# Array is still undefined even assigning in subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular app the array `productLocations` is assigned in `ngOnInit` method in subscription and later on used in a method but it still is undefined. From searching on Stackoverflow everyone is saying to move assignment in subscription. It is already in subscription but I receive error. How to correctly execute things in sequence?

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at AddProductComponent.populateProductLocation
```

**Component File**

```
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  form: FormGroup;
  productManufacturerOptions: ProductManufacturer[] = [];
  filteredProductManufacturerOptions: Observable<ProductManufacturer[]>;
  productModelOptions: ProductModel[] = [];
  filteredProductModelOptions: Observable<ProductModel[]>;
  productCategoryOptions: ProductCategory[] = [];
  filteredProductCategoryOptions: Observable<ProductCategory[]>;

  product: Product = new Product();
  branches: Branch[] = [];
  productLocations: ProductLocation[];
  productPrices: ProductPrice[];
  priceLists: PriceList[] = [];
  editMode = false;
  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;
  fileToUpload: File = null;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private productManufacturerService: ProductManufacturerService,
    private productModelService: ProductModelService,
    private productCategoryService: ProductCategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private branchService: BranchService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _fuseProgressBarService: FuseProgressBarService,
    private priceListService: PriceListService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
    this.initForm();
    if (this.route.snapshot.url[0].path == 'edit' && localStorage.getItem("editProductId")) {
      this.editMode = true;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._fuseProgressBarService.show();
    if (this.editMode) {
      this.productService.get(localStorage.getItem("editProductId"))
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
          this.product = new Product(result);
          console.log("Product", this.product);
          // this.productLocations = result.locations;
          this.productLocations = this.product.locations;
          this.productPrices = this.product.prices;
          this.populateUpdateData(result);
        });
    }

    forkJoin([this.productManufacturerService.getList(),
    this.productModelService.getList(),
    this.productCategoryService.getList(),
    this.branchService.getList(),
    this.priceListService.getList()
    ])
      .subscribe((results: any) => {
        this.productManufacturerOptions = results[0];
        this.productManufacturerStart();

        this.productModelOptions = results[1];
        this.productModelStart();

        this.productCategoryOptions = results[2];
        this.productCategoryStart();

        this.branches = results[3];
        this.priceLists = results[4];
      },
        error => { },
        () => {
          if (this.editMode) {
            this.populateProductLocations();
            this.populatePriceLists();
          }
          else {
            this.initProductLocations();
            this.initPriceLists();
          }
          this._fuseProgressBarService.hide();
        });
  }

  initForm() {
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
      id: [''],
      partNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      replaceNumbers: this._formBuilder.array([]),
      manufacturer: [null, Validators.required],
      model: [null, Validators.required],
      category: [null, Validators.required],
      cost: ['', Validators.required],
      locations: this._formBuilder.array([]),
      prices: this._formBuilder.array([]),
      featuredImage: [null]
    });
  }

  initProductLocations() {
    this.branches.forEach(branch => {
      this.initProductLocation(branch)
    });
  }
  initProductLocation(branch) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['locations'];
    var a = this._formBuilder.group({
      branch: [branch, Validators.required],
      location: [null, Validators.required],
      quantity: [null, Validators.required]
    });
    control.push(a);
  }
  populateProductLocations() {
    this.branches.forEach(branch => {
      this.populateProductLocation(branch)
    });
  }
  populateProductLocation(branch) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['locations'];
    var a;
    var productLocationBranchIds = [];    
    this.productLocations.forEach(productLocation => {
      productLocationBranchIds.push(productLocation.branch.id)
    });
    console.log("ProdIDS", productLocationBranchIds);
    if (productLocationBranchIds.includes(branch.id)) {
      this.productLocations.forEach(productLocation => {
        if (branch.id == productLocation.branch.id) {
          a = this._formBuilder.group({
            branch: [productLocation.branch, Validators.required],
            location: [productLocation.location, Validators.required],
            quantity: [productLocation.quantity, Validators.required]
          });
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("In else");
      a = this._formBuilder.group({
        branch: [branch, Validators.required],
        location: [null, Validators.required],
        quantity: [null, Validators.required]
      });
    }
    control.push(a);
  }


  initPriceLists() {
    this.priceLists.forEach(priceList => {
      this.initPriceList(priceList)
    });
  }
  initPriceList(priceList) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['prices'];
    var a = this._formBuilder.group({
      priceList: [priceList, Validators.required],
      price: [null, Validators.required]
    });
    control.push(a);
  }

  populatePriceLists() {
    this.priceLists.forEach(priceList => {
      this.populatePriceList(priceList)
    });
  }
  populatePriceList(priceList) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['prices'];
    var a;
    var productPricesPriceListIds = [];
    this.productPrices.forEach(productPrice => {
      productPricesPriceListIds.push(productPrice.priceList.id)
    });
    if (productPricesPriceListIds.includes(priceList.id)) {
      this.productPrices.forEach(productPrice => {
        if (priceList.id == productPrice.priceList.id) {
          a = this._formBuilder.group({
            priceList: [productPrice.priceList, Validators.required],
            price: [productPrice.price, Validators.required]
          });
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      a = this._formBuilder.group({
        priceList: [priceList, Validators.required],
        price: [null, Validators.required]
      });
    }
    control.push(a);
  }

  get replaceNumbers(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('replaceNumbers') as FormArray;
  }
  createReplaceNumber(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      partNumber: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  addExistingReplaceNumber(value): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      partNumber: [value, Validators.required]
    });
  }
  addReplaceNumber() {
    this.replaceNumbers.push(this.createReplaceNumber());
  }
  removeReplaceNumber(index: number) {
    this.replaceNumbers.removeAt(index);
  }

  populateUpdateData(product) {
    this.form.get('id').setValue(product.id);
    this.form.get('partNumber').setValue(product.partNumber);
    this.form.get('description').setValue(product.description);
    this.form.get('manufacturer').setValue(product.manufacturer);
    this.form.get('model').setValue(product.model);
    this.form.get('category').setValue(product.category);
    this.form.get('cost').setValue(product.cost);
    let rs = product.replaceNumbers;
    rs.forEach(element => {
      this.replaceNumbers.push(this.addExistingReplaceNumber(element.partNumber));
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._unsubscribeAll.next();
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely happening because the following block is being executed sooner than the subscription:

```
          if (this.editMode) {
            this.populateProductLocations();
            this.populatePriceLists();
          }
```

To verify this, you can do a console.log (or put a breakpoint) in that block and also in the subscription where you are assigning a value.

You should consider refactoring your code, so that `this.populateProductLocations()` comes after `this.productLocations = this.product.locations;` in the same code block, or waits until `this.productService.get(localStorage.getItem("editProductId"))` completes (maybe with a `swithcMap`, `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom`).

## with ForkJoin

`forkJoin` should work too since it waits for all observables to complete, and since you already have it, you can move your code into the forkJoin, something like this (I commented out existing code to clarify what was added):

```
forkJoin([
  // this.productManufacturerService.getList(),
  // this.productModelService.getList(),
  // this.productCategoryService.getList(),
  // this.branchService.getList(),
  // this.priceListService.getList(),
  this.productService.get(localStorage.getItem("editProductId"))
])
  .subscribe((results: any) => {
    // this.productManufacturerOptions = results[0];
    // this.productManufacturerStart();

    // this.productModelOptions = results[1];
    // this.productModelStart();

    // this.productCategoryOptions = results[2];
    // this.productCategoryStart();

    // this.branches = results[3];
    // this.priceLists = results[4];

    this.product = new Product(result);
    this.productLocations = this.product.locations;
    this.productPrices = this.product.prices;
    this.populateUpdateData(results[5]);
  },
```

Comment: Can you point to some examples of `switchMap, combineLatest, withLatestFrom` ?

Comment: @usmanwalana check the updated example with forkJoin. It's not tested, but give it a try.